# Accessing a string from an if function inside of the returned program

Tags: c#, discord.net

Pretty much, I want to use the variable 'username' in the program that the if function returns, however this program is located in my program.cs, and the if function is not.

Wasn't able to get the public static string in the if function, maybe this is obvious to experienced coders but I'm a beginner.

I tested it out by having the console print the variable value, with no success.

The if function:

```
public class WeeWoo : ChatBot
{

    public static Dictionary<string, string> whitelisted;

    static WeeWoo()
    {
        string json = File.ReadAllText("whitelists/walls.json");
        var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(json);
        whitelisted = data.ToObject<Dictionary<string, string>>();
    }

    public override void GetTextAsync(string text)
    {
        string message = "";
        string username = "";
        text = GetVerbatim(text);

        if (text.Contains("-> me"))
        {
            text = text.Replace("[", String.Empty).Replace("]", String.Empty).Replace(" -> me", String.Empty);
            String[] args = text.Split(' ');
            username = args[1];
            message = args[2];
            if (message.Equals("weewoo") && (whitelisted.ContainsKey(username)))
            {
                Program.WeeWoo();
            }
        }
    }
    public static string username;
```

Comment: Can you show how Json return the data...

Comment: pretty sure the issue is here `username = args[1];` , you are trying to assign `args[1];` which is null or empty to `username`, so `username `  will not have any value

Comment: I got it by removing the `string username = "";` Thank you!